# back button functionality in android app

Tags: android, back-button, back-button-control

I have to develop one android app. Here I wish to go back means I have used keyboard button only.but am shouldn't use keyboard back button. I wish to use the back button function for all activities.

For example:

If I have to click on the customize back button means I should able to go to the previous screen. How can I do?

Comment: android is not provide direct back button to go back activity but write programically add button

Comment: how can i wire the code for programatically

Comment: @user1780331 Don't finish previous activity and then try.

Comment: i think problem solve..right ?

Comment: yes.problem is solved successfully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MainActivity :

```
next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

SecondActivity :

```
pre.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

when you want to go back write the following line it will navigates you to back.

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

Here if you want to remove the device back button functionality remove the same line in onBackPressed() by overriding like below

```
@Override
protected void onBackPressed()
{
}
```

Comment: Hi  if i have to click on the customize back button means i should able to go to the previous screen.how can i do

Comment: @user1780331 just call the YourActivity.super.onBackPressed() in the customized back button's onClick(). It worked for and should work for you. I have given you the explaination in my answer itself

Answer (score -1):

You can create a back button, and in onclick() function, you need only call this :
this.finish()

Answer (score -1):

Write this code, few months ago i have used this :-

```
ImageButton back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
finish();
}
});
```

Comment: Button back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
  back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
  finish();
  }
  });  i have used this code.i have to run the app means and view more pages after click the custom back button means am getting first page only.but i wish to need the previous screen

Comment: now first of all i want to know that where you have putted that code in header or somewhere else if header so it will come in all...